# show image using OpenGL on android

Tags: android, opengl-es, camera

I'm working on an Android project where I need to display the camera preview using OpenGL. However I'm always getting a steady white picture on one device (Galaxy Nexus) and a black one on another device (HTC One X). The code where I suppose there is the error is listed below.

This first method `loadGLTexture` is called inside `onSurfaceCreated` and is followed by other gl initialization.

```
public void loadGLTexture(GL10 gl, Context context)
{

    // harcoded size
    // int width = 640;
    // int height = 480;

    // I'm dealing with RGB565 image, so 2 byte per pixels.
    image = new byte[640*480*2];

    // native method that take the new frame from the camera buffer
    Native.takeCurrentFrame(image); 

    // generate one texture pointer
    gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

    // set filter parameters
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

    // allocate the buffer for glTexImage2D
    byte_buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(image.length * 2);
    byte_buffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    byte_buffer.put(image);
    byte_buffer.position(0);

    gl.glTexImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL10.GL_RGB, 640, 480, 0, GL10.GL_RGB, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5, byte_buffer);
}
```

This second method `draw` is called inside `onDrawFrame`

```
public void draw(GL10 gl)
{
    // update the texture with new image from camera
    Native.takeCurrentFrame(image);
    byte_buffer.put(image);
    byte_buffer.position(0);

    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

    // Point to buffers
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);


    gl.glTexImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL10.GL_RGB, 640, 480, 0, GL10.GL_RGB, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5, byte_buffer);
    // Set the face rotation
    gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);

    // Point to vertex and coord buffer
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);

    // Draw the vertices as triangle strip
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertices.length / 3);

    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
}
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

ok, I made a little stupid error, the texture was not power of two. Strange enough that, in this case, you don't get any error about the wrong resolution.